# Cannot get data to display even though it is counted

Tags: c++

I am trying to show all data from a text document. The program shows it has successfully read 14 records, which is correct. However, when I have it show all, it displays ().  I have marked where I think my problems occur. The problem occurs throughout my program (all empty returns) but if I get some help with showAll i figure I could apply it elsewhere. Note: I have removed portions of my code.

```
struct Book
{
string title;
string author;
};


int loadData (Book books[], string);
void showAll (Book books[], int count);
int showBooksByAuthor (int string);
int showBooksByTitle (int string);

int loadData(Book books, string inputFileName)
{
ifstream inputFile;
int i = 0;

inputFile.open(inputFileName.c_str());
if ( ! inputFile.is_open())
{
    cout << "Unable to open input file." << endl;
    return -1;
}

while( ! inputFile.eof())
{
    getline(inputFile, books.title);
    getline(inputFile, books.author);
    i++;
}
return i;
}

void showAll(Book books[], int count) //This may need fixing, the only way I 
                               // was able to get this to work is by removing 
                               //  Book books[] from void showAll. So the 
                               // function would read void showAll(int 
                               // count).  It is a requirement that I use 
                               // int showAll(Book books[], int count)
{
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    cout << books[i].title << " (" << books[i].author << ")" << endl;
}
}


int main()
{
int count;
int i = 0;

string inputFileName;
string title;
string name;
string word;

char reply;

cout << "Location of library file: ";
cin >> inputFileName;
count = loadData(books[i], inputFileName); //This may need fixing

loadData(books[i], inputFileName); //This may need fixing
cout << count << " Records loaded successfully." << endl << endl;

cout << "Enter Q to (Q)uit, A to search (A)uthor, T to search (T)itle, "
     << endl << "S to (S)how all: ";
cin >> reply;

switch(reply)
{
case 'S':
    cout << endl;
    showAll(books, count); //This may need fixing
    break;

case 's':
    cout << endl;
    showAll(books, count); //This may need fixing
    break;
}
return 0;
```

}

I expect my results to display the title (author) for showAll. I do not get any returns for any of my functions. I think my problem is correctly using the struct Book books[]. I tried changing around some variables but end up getting erros.

The actual result is ().  No errors. I have little experience with structs ad arrays, or coding in general for that matter. I hope I have explained things well enough. Thanks for any input.

Comment: `loadData` fills `Book books` *local* variable, not `i`-th `books` array item. You should read about "pass by value vs pass by reference". Also `Book books[]` function parameters most likely are not what you think they are.